Pgadmin throws error while comparing UUID against Collection of UUIDs using IN operator
I have the following query, where I want to compare a UUID against a list of UUIDs using IN operator.
PREPARE testquery (UUID[]) AS
SELECT 
    ven.initialization_status, 
    ven.is_degraded, 
    s.hostname, 
    s.operational_status 
FROM virtual_edge_node ven 
LEFT JOIN virtual_edge_node_reported_status s ON ven.id = s.virtual_edge_node_id 
LEFT JOIN virtual_edge_group veg ON ven.ve_group_id = veg.id 
WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR (ven.site_id IN (SELECT UNNEST($1)) OR (ven.is_inherited_site = true AND veg.site_id IN (SELECT UNNEST($1)))));

EXECUTE testquery(ARRAY['4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28c','4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28d']::UUID[]);

When I execute the query, I get the following error:
"ERROR:  parameter $1 of type uuid[] cannot be coerced to the expected type uuid
LINE 1: EXECUTE testquery(ARRAY['4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28c..."
I have also tried the following, but this also results in the same error:
"EXECUTE testquery(ARRAY['4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28c'::UUID,'4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28d'::UUID]::UUID[]);
"
What am I doing wrong here? 

Edit: I have also tried ANY instead of IN, but got the same error.
PREPARE testquery (UUID[]) AS
SELECT 
    ven.initialization_status, 
    ven.is_degraded, 
    s.hostname, 
    s.operational_status 
FROM virtual_edge_node ven 
LEFT JOIN virtual_edge_node_reported_status s ON ven.id = s.virtual_edge_node_id 
LEFT JOIN virtual_edge_group veg ON ven.ve_group_id = veg.id 
WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR (ven.site_id = ANY($1)) OR (ven.is_inherited_site = true AND veg.site_id=ANY(($1))));

EXECUTE testquery(ARRAY['4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28c'::UUID,'4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28d'::UUID]::UUID[]);


The query name in the error EXECUTE eng11931(ARRAY['4de9127e-8178-46b3-b26f-3d61cdc9b28c..."  does not match the PREPARE name testquery. Also you probably want to use ANY, saves the unnest.

@AdrianKlaver Thank you for your suggestion. The name was not edited properly and reflected the ticket I was working on. I had also tried ANY as you suggested, but I still got the same error. I have added the query in the edit part.

Maybe the prepared statement was already created with a single uuid parameter? select * from pg_prepared_statements where name='testquery';


This prepare array_test (int[]) as select 1 = any($1); execute array_test (array[1 ,2, 3]); t works for me. 2) Try the query in psql. 3) Add the complete error message to the question text.


@JGH. Thank you. You are correct. That was the case. I deleted the prepared statement using DEALLOCATE PREPARE testquery, and then prepared it again and executed, which worked.
